# loop stuck on Trigger postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to create a trigger to controle parameters aren't NULL, but when i try to INSERT for example:

```
INSERT INTO puntuacions(puntuacio, contingut, data) VALUES (6,NULL,CURRENT_DATE);
```

Console start on a big LOOP trying to make INSERT inside function. Im not sure if i must do INSERT on function or at end of trigger.
BTW on avg select im trying to set an AVG value from a SELECT to insert on table.
I have this code:

FUNCTION:

```
create or replace function p_controla() returns trigger as $controla_puntuacions$
begin
IF new.puntuacio IS NULL OR new.contingut IS NULL OR new.data IS NULL
THEN
RAISE 'SIUSPLAU OMPLE TOTES LES DADES DE LA TAULA';
ELSE
INSERT INTO puntuacions(puntuacio, contingut, data) VALUES (new.puntuacio,new.contingut,new.data);
UPDATE continguts SET puntuacio = (SELECT AVG(puntuacio) FROM puntuacions WHERE contingut = new.contingut) WHERE idcontingut = new.contingut;
RAISE ' OK! ';
END IF;
END;
$controla_puntuacions$ language plpgsql;
```

TRIGGER:

```
create trigger controla_puntuacions
before insert on puntuacions
for each row execute procedure p_controla();
```

Comment: This trigger basically implements a constraint. WHY?

Comment: Why not just define those columns as `NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

There are four problems with this trigger:

1. You expect that `INSERT INTO puntuacions` inserts a record which is handled by a trigger. A trigger does not work this way. `INSERT INTO puntuacions` in the trigger function instructs the database to insert another row. It will also fire this trigger again and will cause an infinite recursion. The row being inserted is in `new`. Values in `new` will be inserted to this table after the trigger returns `new`.
2. `UPDATE continguts` based on data in puntuacions is not appropriate in the before insert trigger, because the row is not inserted yet.
3. `RAISE ' OK! '` raises an exception. So, the insert won't complete correctly even if all values are not null.
4. The trigger lacks `return`. When you fix 3, this will lead to a runtime error.

One issue is with the syntax `for each row execute procedure`. This syntax still works, but it is old-fashioned and now it is deprecated. The keyword `FUNCTION` should be used here instead of `PROCEDURE`.

For updating continguts you can create an after insert trigger.
If you want to insert a row after the trigger completes, it has to return `new`.
If you want just to display a message "OK", you can use `RAISE NOTICE`.

Potential solution:

The function for a before insert trigger:

```
create or replace function p_controla() returns trigger as $controla_puntuacions$
begin
IF new.puntuacio IS NULL OR new.contingut IS NULL OR new.data IS NULL
THEN
RAISE 'SIUSPLAU OMPLE TOTES LES DADES DE LA TAULA';
ELSE
RAISE NOTICE ' OK! ';
END IF;
RETURN new;
END;
$controla_puntuacions$ language plpgsql;
```

After insert trigger function:

```
create or replace function puntuacions_after_ins() returns trigger as $puntuacions_after_ins$
begin
UPDATE continguts SET puntuacio = (SELECT AVG(puntuacio) FROM puntuacions WHERE contingut = new.contingut) WHERE idcontingut = new.contingut;
RETURN new;
END;
$puntuacions_after_ins$ language plpgsql;
```

After insert trigger:

```
create trigger puntuacions_after_ins
after insert on puntuacions
for each row execute function puntuacions_after_ins();
```

The return value in the after insert function is ignored, but anyway this function has to return something.